# How can I establish an inequality between $|\frac1n \sum_{i=1}^nX_i|$ and $\frac1n\sum^n_{i=1}|X_i|$ where $X_i \sim N(0,1)$?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, normal-distribution, expected-value, inequality

> Let $X_1, \ldots , X_n$ be a random sample from a $N(0,1)$ population. Define $Y_1=|\frac1n \sum_{i=1}^nX_i|$ and $Y_2=\frac1n\sum^n_{i=1}|X_i|$. Find a relationship between $E(Y_1)$ and $E(Y_2)$.

I have a feeling that I will need to use Jensen's Inequality here. Since $X_i \sim N(0,1)$, the linear combination $\sum_{i=1}^nX_i \sim N(0,n)$.

$E(Y_1)=\frac1n \cdot E(|\sum_{i=1}^nX_i|)$

$E(Y_2)=\frac1n \cdot E(\sum_{i=1}^n|X_i|)$

However, I am not too sure how to compute $E(Y_1)$ or $E(Y_2)$ from this step since there are absolute values. Do I have to use a cdf approach?

Comment: Can you find a relationship between $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ that holds pointwise?

Comment: @user257566 I am not sure if I know what you mean

Comment: For example, for numbers $a$ and $b$, what can you say about $|a+b|$ compared to $|a| + |b|$?

Comment: @user257566 $|a| + |b| \ge |a+b|$. So, $\Sigma^n_{i=1}|X_i| \ge |\Sigma_{i=1}^n X_i|$. However, I would like to show a rigorous proof of this and potentially calculate $E(Y_1)$ and $E(Y_2)$.

Comment: that's right. now, using that $Y_2$ is pointwise larger than $Y_1$ to (rigorously) prove your result just relies on a simple use of that bigger RVs have bigger means (see e.g. thm 1.6.1 of durrett probability, v5)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming independent $X_i$, the mean $\frac{1}{n}\sum X_i$ is also normal, i.e. $N(0,1/n)$. Absolute value of it is [Half-normal](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Half-normal_distribution), which has mean $E[Y_1]=\frac{\sigma\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{\pi}}=\sqrt{\frac{2}{n\pi}}$. For $Y_2$ we can find the expected value directly:
$$E[Y_2]=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n E[|X_i|]=E[|X_i|]=\sqrt\frac{2}{\pi}$$

This means $\sqrt n E[Y_1]=E[Y_2]$. I think an equality is better than inequality.

Comment: I understand how you got that $\frac{1}{n}\Sigma X_i \sim N(0,1/n)$. Is there a way to find $E(Y_1)$ without having to use the half-normal distribution?

Comment: Calculating $E[|X|]$ for a zero-mean normal RV is straightforward (let $x^2/2\sigma^2=u$): $$E[|X|]=2\int_0^\infty\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}xe^{-x^2/2\sigma^2}dx=2\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_0^\infty e^{-u}du=\sigma\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}$$

Answer (score 6):

**Answer:**

Whatever the distribution of $X_1,...,X_n$,

$$\mathbb{E} Y_2 \geq \mathbb{E} Y_1.$$

**Details:**

For any $n$ numbers $X_1,..., X_n$ it is true that

$$ \sum_i |X_i| \geq |\sum_i X_i|$$

and dividing both sides by $n$:

$$ \frac{1}{n}\sum_i |X_i| \geq \frac{1}{n}|\sum_i X_i| = |\frac{1}{n}\sum_i X_i|.$$

Now, the key word is 'any', that means that if we take integrals of both sides of the above inequality, the integrand of the left hand side is **uniformly** higher than the integrand of the right hand side, i.e.

$$ \mathbb{E} Y_2 = \int \frac{1}{n}\sum_i |X_i| dX_1 ...dX_n \geq \int |\frac{1}{n}\sum_i X_i| dX_1...dX_n = \mathbb{E} Y_1.$$